# How create an executable file or an set up file of an Java web application

Tags: struts2, struts1

I would like to know how to create an set up file or an executable file of a java web application in which I have used Struts and jsp for development in net beans 7.1.2 IDE. So please Help me.

Comment: can you be more clear about your requirments

Answer (score 1):

You need stuts plugins (something like that [struts2 plugin for netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/23467/netbeans-struts2-support))

and you can find many examples how to create web app with struts for example this

- [example 1](http://devtalks.blogspot.com/2009/07/create-struts2-project-in-netbeans.html)
- [example 2](http://beans.seartipy.com/2008/07/30/hello-world-web-application-using-struts-2-in-netbeans-ide-61/)

Answer (score 1):

Download excelsior and run your Java EE web project as example.exe file

```
http://www.excelsior-usa.com/
```